# Javascript div onclick and back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason, i have this two functions in my javascript, and both seems to work.
The first one, is when user click on one of two divs, it will show the other div, depending on wich was clicked.

The second one, is when the user is on the second div, and clicks on back.

All this is working, but when the user return to the first div, and i click on one of two divs, this isnt going to the second div.

It's closing both divs.

`First Div with two options:`

```
<div class="firstQuestion">
     <div class="male" onclick="secondQuestion(this);"></div>
     <div class="female" onclick="secondQuestion(this);"></div>
</div>
```

`Second div, with back button:`

```
<div class="secondQuestion">
     <form class="formAconselhamento" id="male">
     <input type="button" id="save_value_male" class="back" name="save_value" onclick="comeBack(this); return false;"/>
     <input type="button" id="save_value_male" class="next" name="save_value" />
     </form>
</div>
```

`Javascript functions:`

```
function secondQuestion(divID)
{
    var clicado = $("#"+$(divID).attr('class'));
    $(".firstQuestion").hide();
    $("#"+$(divID).attr('class')).show();
}

function comeBack(divID)
{
    var backButton = $(divID).attr('id');

    if ( backButton == 'save_value_female' || backButton == 'save_value_male' )
    {
        $(".secondQuestion").hide();
        $(".firstQuestion").show();
    }
}
```

How can i resolve my issue?

Comment: `id`s must be unique within the document.

Comment: And `this` is an element itself you don't need to use `#` here!

Comment: @Teemu but the next input, doesnt have anything. It is because of that? O_O

Comment: Make ids unique, and if problem persists, it will be the time to search for another problems

Comment: @Regent i have changed the input ids to be unique, and the problem it is the same. any ideas?

Comment: I've created a fiddle of your code, you might want to create an example containing `#female` too. Feel free to modify and save the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwV4Y/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `comeBack` function you hide `<div class="secondQuestion">` instead of `<form class="formAconselhamento" id="male">`

Try something like:

```
function comeBack(divID)
{
    var backButton = $(divID).attr('id');

    if ( backButton == 'save_value_female' || backButton == 'save_value_male' )
    {
        $(divID).closest("form").hide();
        $(".firstQuestion").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3629180 You're welcome. And Teemu's modified fiddle (maybe it'll be helpful for someone): http://jsfiddle.net/DwV4Y/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .maincat{background: #eef;}.subcat{background: #abc;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="maincat">
    <div class="type" rel='one'>first</div>
    <div class="type" rel='two'>second</div>
    <div class="type" rel='three'>third</div>
</div>
<div class="subcat" style="display: none">
<a href="#" class="back">back</a>
    <div id="one">
        first content
    </div>
    <div id="two">
         second content
    </div>
<div id="three">
         third content
    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".type").click(function(){
$(".maincat").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).attr('rel')).show().siblings().hide();
    $('.subcat').show();$('.back').show();
});

$(".back").click(function(){
    $('.subcat').children().hide();$(".maincat").show();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in order to be easier to understand it. Thanks

Comment: To show appropriate content when an option is clicked, with back link to go back to options.

Comment: @acostela I have tried to explain hope I m being clear.have a nice day